# Flutter Ink Image splash

Tags: flutter, ripple-effect

I need ripple effect when tap image like facebook my day. Use `Ink.image` for grid view image not work in my code. I want to ripple when on tap action trigger on my image but my code only work for pressing. Also add the `Material` widget to the parent of `Ink.image` widget. Please solve me.
This is my code.

```
Expanded(
                        child: GridView.builder(
                            gridDelegate:
                                SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                    crossAxisCount: 2),
                            controller: _scrollController,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            itemCount: _agentsList.length,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return Stack(
                                children: [
                                      Container(
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(margin),
                                        child: ClipRRect(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(19.0)),
                                          child: Material(
                                              clipBehavior:Clip.hardEdge,
                                              child: Ink.image(
                                                image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                                                  _agentsList[index].agentPhoto,
                                                ),
                                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                child: InkWell(
                                                  splashFactory:InkSplash.splashFactory,
                                                  onTap: () {
                                                    widget.viewType =
                                                        Agent.current != null
                                                            ? "hello"
                                                            : "";
                                                    Navigator.of(context)
                                                        .pushNamed('/ProfileView',
                                                            arguments: {
                                                          "agent":
                                                              _agentsList[index]
                                                        });
                                                  },
                                                ),
                                              )
                                            ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                ],
                              );
                            }))
```

Comment: ok, you are missing splash effect ?

Comment: Where can I add splash effect parameter?  In```InkWell``` widget? I think there is no splash effect parameter in ```InkWell``` widget.

Comment: I'm not aware of the facebook splash effect , can you include the desire out on question. And there are some parameters on `InkWell` can be used to change the behavior of the  UI.

Comment: That is work, I change highlightColor option in ```InkWell``` widget. In debug mode, this animation is little slow ,so I think this does not work at first. My fault.